# Can't Import DLL after obsfucation .net

Tags: .net, vb.net

[image]

I've obsfucated my DLL, and try to import it, but It gives me errors.

Comment: What the error is exactly?

Comment: It says that I need to Generate Class for DBLibrary, means, its not imported properly.

Comment: Your namespace has the same name is your class?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on obfuscator application there should be a way to mark classes/methods not to be obfuscated. You should use it for external api you want to provide.